# MVC override AllowAnonymous attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, custom-attributes, filterattribute

Is there a way to override `AllowAnonymous` attribute? I have implemented custom authorization that loads user menus & buttons from database as below:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyCustomAuthorization()); // Custom Authorization for Rights & Priveleges
}
```

The above works fine.

Now I want to allow access to some action if a user is authenticated, no need to check authorization in this case. Example:

```
[Authorize]
public class MenusAndButtonsController : BaseController
{
    [Authenticated] // my custom attribute that will check if user is logged in or not
    public JsonResult GetGeneralMenuAndButtons()
    {
        using (MealPlannerAuthorizationEntities repository = new MealPlannerAuthorizationEntities())
        {
            var MenusAndButtons = repository.MP_AUTH_Menus.Where(x => x.IsButton == false && x.IsListButton == false).Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.MenuName, Value = c.MenuId }).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayText).ToList();
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = MenusAndButtons }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `AllowAnonymous`, I am trying to create my own custom attribute `[Authenticated]` that will check if the user is logged in or not. If user is logged in it will return true and the `GetGeneralMenuAndButtons` will continue its operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Actually `AllowAnonymous` class is simple empty sealed attribute class.

So when we decorate an action method with `AllowAnonymous` attribute, the `onAuthorization` method of `AuthorizeAttribute` simply ignores authorization and authentication checking. So in my case I also had to create an attribute (a blank sealed class inheriting from attribute class) and modify the `OnAuthorization` method little bit.

Below is the complete implementation:

```
public sealed class AuthenticateAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AuthenticateAttribute() { }
}
```

Then override the `onAuthorization` method of Authorize attribute (of course I am assuming you already have custom authorization filter implemented).

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    bool IsAuthenticAttribute =
        (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthenticateAttribute), true) ||
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthenticateAttribute), true)) &&
        filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    if (!IsAuthenticAttribute)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Finally decorate your action method with our new Authenticate attribute:

```
[Authenticate]
public JsonResult GetParentMenus()
{
    using (MealPlannerAuthorizationEntities repository = new MealPlannerAuthorizationEntities())
    {
        var parentMenus = repository.MP_AUTH_Menus.Where(x => x.IsButton == false && x.IsListButton == false).Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.MenuName, Value = c.MenuId }).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayText).ToList();
        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = parentMenus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```