# ASP.NET MVC AllowAnonymous attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

`AllowAnonymous` attribute is not working at all in my MVC project *(target framework 4.7)*.

I have tried everything on the internet but still, I am always redirected to the login page.
Even I have tried: [mvc-override-allowanonymous-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950283/mvc-override-allowanonymous-attribute)

What is actually I am missing?

This is my controller:

```
using OnDemand.Helper;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnDemand.Controllers
{
    [App_Auth.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
    public class AdminDashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DashboardHelper _dashboardHelper;
        public AdminDashboardController()
        {
            _dashboardHelper = new DashboardHelper();
        }
        [App_Auth.AllowAnonymous] // Not Working
        [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous] // Not Working
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_dashboardHelper.DashboardData());
        }
    }
}
```

Filter configuration:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OnDemand.App_Auth;

namespace OnDemand.App_Start
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute()); //check session expire and redirect to login
        }
    }
}
```

Global asax class:

```
using OnDemand.App_Start;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace OnDemand
{
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Session_Start()
        {
            Session.Timeout = 24 * 60; // return 24 hours
        }
    }
}
```

Custom `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous` attribute classes:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace OnDemand.App_Auth
{
    public class AuthorizeAccessAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        private readonly int code;
        public AuthorizeAccessAttribute(int code)
        {
            this.code = code;
        }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var hasAccess = false;

            if (httpContext.Session["Roles"] == null) return false;

            if (SectionsAndFeatures.HasAccess(code, httpContext.Session["Roles"] != null ? httpContext.Session["Roles"].ToString() : string.Empty))
            {
                hasAccess = true;
            }
            return hasAccess;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                   new RouteValueDictionary
                                   {
                                       { "action", "UnauthorizedAccess" },
                                       { "controller", "Home" },
                                       { "area", "" }
                                   });  //new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You are not authorized.");
        }
    }

    public class AllowAnonymousAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AllowAnonymousAttribute()
        {

        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            bool IsAuthenticAttribute =
                (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)) &&
                filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            if (!IsAuthenticAttribute)
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web configuration:

```
<location path="AdminDashboard/Index">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: `App_Auth.AllowAnonymous` i have never seen this attribute, is it custom? what happen if you rid of it?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes it is custom, code also mention in the question.

Comment: @TinyDeveloper in that case ASP.NET won't know what to do with it. ASP.NET authentication isn't broken. It doesn't need fixing and custom classes. If it was, hundreds of thousands of developers would have noticed 10-12 years ago.  Why did you think you need that attribute? What was the original problem?

Comment: I started with a simple and easy way first, but it did not work.

Comment: Create a new MVC project using the steps in [Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset). Check what's different between the template and your current code or better yet, build your application on top of the template.

Comment: I tried a simple way as well, and here are the results: [link](http://2518-119-63-134-60.ngrok.io/AdminDashboard)

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? If you use Windows Authentication at the IIS level, it doesn't matter what attributes you use. Authentication is performed by IIS itself and the calls are intercepted before they even reach your web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we are using a custom method, I just needed to include my controller name in that list:

```
public static List<string> ByPassController()
        {
            try
            {
                return new List<string>
                {
                    "Access",
                    "InterpreterSelection",
                    "Language",
                    "Log",
                    "CallBack",
                    "Controller",
                    "IvrOnDemand",
                    "Main",
                    "CallDetail",
                    "ConferenceParticipant",
                    "DashBoardData",
                    "CallWaitingResponse",
                    "IVRRejoinParticipant",
                    "IVRAuto",
                    "OnDemand",
                    "Assignment",
                    "SilentListenCallback",
                    "AutoOnDemand",
                    "StelCallLogs",
                    "DialOut",
                    "AdminDashboard",
                    "Developer"
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogWriter.ErrorLogWriter(nameof(CommonFunction), nameof(ByPassController), ex.Message);
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use it in the standard way? simple AllowAnonymous attribute without duplication or custom attributes.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

Or in your code:

```
using OnDemand.Helper;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnDemand.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AdminDashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DashboardHelper _dashboardHelper;
        public AdminDashboardController()
        {
            _dashboardHelper = new DashboardHelper();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_dashboardHelper.DashboardData());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If simple was working fine, I didn't need to create any custom

Comment: I don't understand why you need to create the custom attribute, for special cases? If you simply need to allow access, I think it better to check why the regular attribute is not working for you.

Comment: Because the `System.Web.MVC.AllowAnonymous` attribute was not working at all.

Comment: this code I wrote at first, but it was not working.

Comment: I think the better approach is to keep it as simple as you can, using custom attributes only increases the complexity.

Comment: @TinyDeveloper simple is working fine for every developer for over 12 years. If your app fails, it has a bug. That bug won't be fixed by adding extra code the runtime knows nothing about. You need to find the bug and *remove* it. Try creating a new project using the ASP.NET MVC wizard with `Individual Accounts` authentication to see how the attributes and web.config actually work

Comment: I tried a simple way as well, and here are the results: [result](https://2518-119-63-134-60.ngrok.io/AdminDashboard) supposed to be unauthorized.

Comment: I changed the code to:

`using OnDemand.Helper;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnDemand.Controllers
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AdminDashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DashboardHelper _dashboardHelper;
        public AdminDashboardController()
        {
            _dashboardHelper = new DashboardHelper();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_dashboardHelper.DashboardData());
        }
    }
}`

but still not working. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: What you posted in the comment has nothing to do with authentication. We can't guess what your application code does, what's missing. Not even what type of authentication you use. We do know that ASP.NET authentication works - all one needs to do is create a new project. Create a new web app project to see how things actually work, then check what's different between that and your code